# Pass a colour picker colour into a variable

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to pass a colour selected from the inbuilt picker into a variable?
Something like this?

```
newColour = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(1)
```

If not, what is the best way to go about getting colours from a GUI into a variable so it is easy for the user to change colours?

Thanks.

Comment: http://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/Show-Color-Palette-Dialog-Box-with-VBA-xlDialogEditColor/  (And please remove the [vb.net] tag if this is VBA.)

Comment: Hi, sorry I meant so that it be simple for a user to change the colour of multiple cells because of how my current application works. and thanks YowE3K, I will give that a read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is asking the user to select a new colour for colour 1, and return `True` to the variable `newColour` if the user selects a colour, or `False` if they cancel.

So you would be able to use your code as

```
newColour = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogEditColor).Show(1)
If newColour Then
    Range("A1").Interior.Color = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(1)
End If
```

Comment: I was hoping it worked somewhat similar to an input box where :

      `recNum = InputBox("Enter the Number you Wish to Recolour:")`

recNum becomes the input,

In the above code I was hoping that the newColour variable would become the colour that was picked in the colour picker

Comment: No, the dialog is editing the workbook colours.  It would be nice if there was a `Dialogs(xlDialogColourChooser)` (especially if they spelled "colour" correctly! ;) ) but there isn't as far as I know.

Comment: So there is no way to pass a colour picker colour into a variable?

Comment: If you wanted to put it into a variable, instead of directly colouring a cell, just use something like `xyz = ActiveWorkbook.Colors(1)`.

Comment: A bit old of an answer but I wanted to add a note that `Thisworkbook.Colors(1)` is stored as an integer so it is possible to store it and use it as such. For example `Dim colornum as integer  colornum = Thisworkbook.Colors(1)`